# How would an atom behave (in terms of atomic particles) if the electrons were much heavier than the nucleus?

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, mass

In other words, does the **mass** of electrically charged particles affect the electromagnetic forces that operate between them ?

Is the electrons revolving around the nucleus simply a consequence of the electro-weak and electromagnetic forces ?

In this case would the atom behave the same if the masses of the nucleus and the electron were inverted (say in a hydrogen atom)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main force keeping the electrons around the nucleus is the electromagnetic one. Electrons do interact gravitationally and weakly but those are very much weaker forces.

In principle if the masses were exactly inverted, it would just change the definition of positive and negative charge, which is arbitrary. Generally changes in mass affect the orbitals.

The [Bohr atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_model) is useful in getting an intuition:

[image: bohrradius]

Please look at the link for the definition of the variables but it is easy to see the mass of the electron in the denominator. The larger the mass the smaller the radius.

There exist [muonic atoms,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_atom#Muonic_atoms) i.e. where an electron has temporarily been replaced by a muon and the orbitals are much smaller and tighter.

> Since a muon is more massive than an electron, the Bohr orbits are closer to the nucleus in a muonic atom than in an ordinary atom, and corrections due to quantum electrodynamics are more important. Study of muonic atoms' energy levels as well as transition rates from excited states to the ground state therefore provide experimental tests of quantum electrodynamics.
>
> Muon-catalyzed fusion is a technical application of muonic atoms.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt and accurate answer.

Am I to understand that the radius of the electrons' orbit is completely independant of the nucleus' mass ?

Would electrons in a Bohr atom behave the same if the nucleus' mass was the same than the electron's ?

Comment: The calculations are done in a system where the nucleus is at rest and the electron in motion, like one planet around a sun at rest system,  thus only the charge is important . The mass of the electron enters because of kinematics. This is the simplest frame. If the center of mass of eletron+nucleus were used the mass of the nucleus would enter with  more complicated formulae. This would not change the relative distance (r) between electron and nucleus. In central potential problems the simplest system to use for solving is where the source of the potential is at rest.